# How can I add more functionalities to my Joomla website?

Tags: joomla

I have a [Joomla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joomla) site, in which I configured the main sections categories and articles.
Now I need to have a slideshow widget, couple of list widgets in my website. Do I need to code it myself? I am very new to Joomla with first project in hand.

Answer (score 3):

Well,
you can extend your basic joomla by installing and configuring various components, modules and plugins.

Here you can get a big collection of available extensions for joomla.

http://extensions.joomla.org